# Forex data from Quandl with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I'm trying to get Currency data from [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com/) with Pandas with this code:

data = Quandl.get('GBPUSD', collapse='weekly', authtoken='XXXXX')

But I'm getting

```
Quandl.Quandl.DatasetNotFound: Dataset not found. Check Quandl code: GBP for errors
```

Comment: I don't think this is the appropriate place to ask as this seems to be about the quandl API and not pandas or python...  But out of curiosity about quandl I took a glance at their page and wonder if you just need to replace GBPUSD with QUANDL/GBPUSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a source like this:

```
    data = Quandl.get('CURRFX/GPBUSD')
```

There are several other sources.
Check https://www.quandl.com/resources/api-for-currency-data for details.